# Подскажите как добавлять Cardview в Recyclerview на kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, recyclerview

У меня естьCardView в котором просто отображается прогресс бары, потом еще 4 Cardview в которые отображается совсем другая информация, все это на главном экране, но они не помещаются, и я хотел бы иметь возможность прокручивать их, подскажите как это можно реализовать, я новичок((

Comment: может быть вам нужен ScrollView, а не Ресайкл?

Comment: Спасибо, только сейчас допер до этого